# How get a login page to go back to the homepage in php

Tags: php, html

I have login code where the user can log into a site and the details are picked up from a database. When the user logs in a want them to be taken back to the homepage of the site, I cant seem to get this to work.

Here is my code

main login

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
   
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <title>Buzz Party | Login</title>
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        </head>
<?php
session_start();
session_destroy();
?>

<body> 
     

    
<table width="300" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">
<tr>
<form name="form1" method="post" action="checklogin.php">
<td>
<table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
<tr>
<td colspan="3"><strong>Member Login </strong></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="78">Username</td>
<td width="6">:</td>
<td width="294"><input name="myusername" type="text" id="myusername"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Password</td>
<td>:</td>
<td><input name="mypassword" type="text" id="mypassword"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Login"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</td>
</form>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

check login

```html
?php

$host="localhost"; // Host name 
$username="root"; // Mysql username 
$password="root"; // Mysql password 
$db_name="login"; // Database name 
$tbl_name="users"; // Table name 

// Connect to server and select databse.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

// username and password sent from form 
$myusername=$_POST['myusername']; 
$mypassword=$_POST['mypassword']; 

// To protect MySQL injection (more detail about MySQL injection)
$myusername = stripslashes($myusername);
$mypassword = stripslashes($mypassword);
$myusername = mysql_real_escape_string($myusername);
$mypassword = mysql_real_escape_string($mypassword);
$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE name='$myusername' and password='$mypassword'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

// Mysql_num_row is counting table row
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);

// If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row
if($count==1){

// Register $myusername, $mypassword and redirect to file "login_success.php"
session_register("sername");
session_register("password"); 
header("location:login.php");
}
else {
echo "Wrong Username or Password";
}
?>
```

login success

```html
<?php
session_start();
if isset($_SESSION['myusername'])
{
header("Location:myindex.php");
}
?>
```

Comment: But what is the problem? Any errors displayed?

Comment: no when the user logins in it doesn't take them back to the index page

Comment: are there any errors??

Comment: no, no error comes up

Comment: (1) [`session_register()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-register.php) is `has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 5.3.0 and REMOVED as of PHP 5.4.0.` and (2) you have `session_register("sername");` so `if isset($_SESSION['myusername'])` will be false.

Comment: just use the conventional `$_SESSION['sername']=$username;` what is wrong with it?, also, if it is not redirecting it means the condition has not been met, meaning no user found? try `echo "I'm in";` inside the condition to check if it actually got in

Comment: Plus, possible typo for "sername" which should read as "username". Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything.

Comment: fixed the spelling mistake and it's still not working

Comment: try printing them both out and check your self if they actually have been set... check if the conditions have been met or not as well by printing something out inside the condition

Comment: should the header go to header("location:login_success.php") instead of login.php? maybe its going to the wrong page. looks like there isn't any output before the header location but if there is the header(location: will not work.

Comment: Why are you sending them back to `header("location:login.php");` which has `session_start(); session_destroy();`. So even if they login correctly, you just destroyed the session, so they are auto logged out again. Should `header("location:login.php");` be `header("location:loginsuccess.php");`?

Comment: it still doesn't work, i'm quite confused

Answer (score 0):

header("location:login.php");  won't work if ANY output has already been sent to the browser.

Either make sure you are not sending anything to the browser before sending the header or you can buffer the output and then send everything when you are ready, like so:

```
ob_start();
// do stuff
header("location:login.php");
echo ob_get_clean();
```